# how to get different samples from same random op in single session

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I am trying to get multiple samples from **xr** by stacking xr op. Now, it seems that it just gives you same values. Is there a way I can get different values or **xr** in single session?

```
import tensorflow as tf
import tensorflow.random as tdr 
import numpy as np

x = 5. # fixe_input 
xr = tdr.uniform(shape=[1],minval=0., maxval=x)
x_list = tf.stack([xr for _ in range(10)]
with tf.Session() as sess:
    print('xlist', sess.run(x_list))
```

Output:

```
xlist [[2.2005057]
 [2.2005057]
 [2.2005057]
 [2.2005057]
 [2.2005057]
 [2.2005057]
 [2.2005057]
 [2.2005057]
 [2.2005057]
 [2.2005057]]
```

Comment: you need to generate the random number *inside* the list comprehension.  Right now, you are just repeating the same single value that the variable `xr` holds

Comment: I get that point but not sure how to do it @JeffH

Comment: standby........

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a way I can get different values or xr in single session?

No, each node is evaluated once. Instead, why not change `shape=[1]` to be `shape=[10]`? That will give you an array of 10 samples from your distribution with a single `sess.run` call.

```
import tensorflow as tf
import tensorflow.random as tdr 
import numpy as np

x = 5. # fixe_input 
xr = tdr.uniform(shape=[10],minval=0., maxval=x)
with tf.Session() as sess:
    print('xlist', sess.run(xr))
```

> xlist [2.6705563  1.477465   2.2741747  0.44075608 0.41182756 3.652794
>    2.3826408  4.6979356  2.0650215  1.4842021 ]

Comment: I actually simplified my problem and it won't be possible for me to just change the shape like you mentioned. I will need to evaluate same op multiple times in the same session but need a different sample.

Answer (score 0):

You are essentially generating the random number once, catching it in a variable, and then copying it as in first part below.  You want to invoke the random function for each item in your list as seen in second part below.

```
In [2]: from random import randint                                              

In [3]: x = randint(1,1000)                                                     

In [4]: random_nums = [x for _ in range(10)]                                    

In [5]: random_nums                                                             
Out[5]: [728, 728, 728, 728, 728, 728, 728, 728, 728, 728]

In [6]: random_nums2 = [randint(1, 1000) for _ in range(10)]                    

In [7]: random_nums2                                                            
Out[7]: [92, 928, 72, 875, 719, 725, 957, 930, 729, 299]

In [8]:
```

Comment: I understand this solution but in my case...xr is coming from distribution and if I apply a random operation on the top of it the sample from xr would not be from the original distribution but from random(original_distribution). In the sample case above you your randoms_nums2 are not coming from the distribution of x but from distribution applied over the distribution of x. Please correct me if I am wrong

Comment: what do you mean "applying a random operation on top of it" and what do you think is doing that?